# PHP won't run under Windows 2012 Server R2 - Installs but nothing else

Tags: php, windows, server

I have a laptop running Windows 10 and a Lenovo server running Windows 2012 Server R2.

I have installed PHP 7.4.3 on my laptop. When I run php -v on the command line I get:

C:\Users\david>php -v
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 17:29:46) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Hence, I know that the install is fine. When I run php - v on the server the command prompt returns but shows nothing:-

[image]

Can anyone suggest what has gone wrong please?

Comment: Did you added the environment variables?

Comment: Yes, I did. The setup is exactly the same between the Windows 10 and the Windows Server machines. I even tried the Microsoft Web Install program but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2019.